# python returns nameError for class name not being defined

Tags: python

I am trying to code a program that calls on an established class from another python file called student. In the file student, a class called StudentInfo is established and **init** checks if the data is valid (eg. grade must be between 9-12, course code must fit format, etc.) I am trying to first take the user's inputs here.

```
import student
import transcript

def add_student(data):
    dataDict = data

    ID = str(len(dataDict) + 1)

    student = StudentInfo(ID, input("Enter the student\'s last name: "), input("Enter the student\'s first name: "), input("Enter the student\'s grade: "), transcript.add_transcript(), input("Is the student registered: "))

    return dataDict
```

When I try to define student as an object of class StudentInfo, it returns
`NameError: name 'StudentInfo' is not defined.`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I thought it might be the inputs but when I removed them it seemed to do the same thing. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to refer to it as `student.StudentInfo`.  Alternatively, change the import to `from student import *` (or `from student import StudentInfo` if that's all you need).

Comment: @TomKarzes Although wildcard imports should be avoided in most scenarios since they pollute the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you forgot to prefix `StudentInfo` with `student`.
You can either replace:

```py
import student
```

With:

```py
from student import StudentInfo
```

Or you can replace:

```py
student = StudentInfo(ID, input("Enter the student\'s last name: "), input("Enter the student\'s first name: "), input("Enter the student\'s grade: "), transcript.add_transcript(), input("Is the student registered: "))
```

With:

```py
student = student.StudentInfo(ID, input("Enter the student\'s last name: "), input("Enter the student\'s first name: "), input("Enter the student\'s grade: "), transcript.add_transcript(), input("Is the student registered: "))
```

On a side note: You shouldn't name variables after imports. Rename the variable `student` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need `student.StudentInfo` if you're using `import student`.

Alternatively, you can import as:

```
from student import StudentInfo
```

To use the code that you have now.